# How to count text in all cells in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, analytics

[image]

Hello friends, I would need your help as I want to count the text in a cell. Data is based in excel.
I have a coulmn, each cell in that column contains multiple categories. And I need to count the existance of those categories in the column. Please see the  attached screenshot for sample Data and expected output. Thanks! :)

Please see the  attached screenshot for sample Data and expected output. Thanks! :)

Comment: `COUNTIFS` with `*`, assuming the text to be counted is never repeated in the same cell.

Comment: You could try this as well: `=LET(a,A2:A8,b,TOCOL(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(","&a,",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(a))))&",",","),3),c,UNIQUE(b),HSTACK(c,MMULT(N(c=TOROW(b)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(b),,,0))))`

Comment: Hey @MayukhBhattacharya thanks for this solution. I was trying to edit this as per my original data but unfortunately, I couldn't.  I have a list of 15 items (which might be increasing in the future), entered in a way that one item will not repeat in a cell but can exist in different cells of the column. I just need the count/ existence of the item in the column, there is no need to write the item list with the help of code, I just need the count in front of the list. Please refer to my screenshot, the expected output is just the count column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming there is no **Excel Constraints** then you could try this following formula.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A8,
     b,TOCOL(TEXTBEFORE(
       TEXTAFTER(","&a,",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(a))))&",",","),3),
     c,UNIQUE(b),
     d,HSTACK(c,MMULT(N(c=TOROW(b)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(b),,,0))),
     VSTACK({"Category","Count"},d))
```

---